# Which formula should I use for finding the center of mass of a system?

Tags: calculus

For example, I have to find the center of mass of a thin plate of constant density covering the region bounded by the curve $y=\sec^2x$, $-\pi/4\leq x\leq\pi/4$, and the x-axis.

The solution calculates the y-coordinate of center of mass by using $$\bar{y}=\frac{M_{x}}{M}$$ However, another formula for $\bar{y}$ is $$\frac{1}{M}\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\delta}{2}(f^{2}(x)-g^{2}(x))dx$$

I'm just wondering why the solution used the first one and not the second one. Are they interchangeable? I understand that I can use the second equation when I have plates bounded by two curves, but is that the only time I can use it? Also, does it matter if the density is constant or varying when deciding which formula to use?

Edit:

[image]

[image]

two curves are $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Also $\delta$ is the density.

Comment: Can you introduce $M$, $M_x$, $\sigma$, $f$ and $g$, please?

Comment: Just edited and added all the formulas you requested. Please let me know if I need to add anything else.

Comment: I don't see any $\sigma$ (lower case Greek letter "sigma") in formula (7). Instead I see a lower case Greek letter "delta", written $\delta$. Is $\delta$ the actual symbol for the density?

Comment: ohhh sorry, yes that was a mistake. Thank you. I will correct it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two formulas in your source are equivalent, provided that $\overset\sim y$ in Equation $(5)$ is defined the way I expect it to be.

But note that there is no factor of $x$ inside the integral in Equation $(7)$.

In the formula $$\int \overset\sim y \, dm,$$
you are integrating over the mass, which you can imagine comes in increments of $dm,$ where the center of mass of each mass increment is $\overset\sim y.$

Obviously if the integral were just giving the average $y$-coordinate of a bunch of arbitrary pieces of the mass of the plate, this would not give a correct answer in general. But what the integral is actually doing is adding up the moments of all of those pieces. Each $y$ coordinate in the integral is literally *weighted* by the amount of mass of the piece of plate associated with that $y$ coordinate.

For Equation $(7)$ we have decided to integrate over the mass in a particular way: you can imagine that we have cut the plate into vertical strips where $dx$ is the width of a vertical strip. Assuming that the upper boundary of the plate is $f(x)$ and the lower boundary is $g(x),$ the mass of a strip is
$dm = \delta (f(x) - g(x))\, dx.$
But since that strip is (in the limit) just a rectangle of width $dx$ with its bottom edge at $y=g(x)$ and its top edge at $y=f(x),$
the average $y$ coordinate of the strip is
$\overset\sim y = \frac12 (f(x) + g(x)).$
Multiply the two things together to get a moment around the $x$ axis:

$$ \overset\sim y \, dm
 = \frac12 (f(x) + g(x)) \cdot \delta (f(x) - g(x))\, dx
 = \frac12 \delta ((f(x))^2 - (g(x))^2)\, dx. $$

In $(5)$ we integrate the moments in a form that looks like the left side of the equation, while in $(7)$ we integrate the moments in a form that looks like the right side.
And then (in either case) we divide the total moment around the $x$-axis by $M$ to get the $y$ coordinate of the center of mass.

Note that this answer assumes the mass distribution is uniform
(constant density, as given in the problem statement).
For non-uniform density you would need a different formula instead of Equation $(7)$. (The formulas in $(5)$ still work if you are careful how you count $dm$.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get from the first formula to the second, if for all values of $x$ in $a \leq x \leq b, ~g(x) \leq y \leq f(x)$ and mass density is either constant or only a function of $x$. This question is a good example where the second formula would work.

If mass density is only a function of $x$ and I will write it as $\delta (x)$,

$ \displaystyle \bar{y}=\frac{M_{x}}{M}$, where $M_x$ is Moment about the x-axis.

$$\begin{aligned} M_x &= \int y ~ dm \\
&=  \iint \delta(x) ~y ~ dA \\
&=  \int_{a}^{b} \delta(x) \left[\int_{g(x)}^{f(x)} y ~ dy \right] dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{a}^{b} \delta(x)\left[(f(x))^2 - (g(x))^2\right]  dx
\end{aligned}$$

So, $$~ \displaystyle \overline y = \frac{1}{2M} \int_{a}^{b} \delta(x) \left[(f(x))^2 - (g(x))^2\right]  dx$$

If mass density is constant and not a function of $x$, it can be taken out of the integral.